# Need help designing my invoice db structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a website where customer can buy subscriptions.
The customer can at any time go to payment history and see what has ben bought.

I'm trying to design the db for creating invoices, but something doesn't seem right for me.

My current setup looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------+
|  Invoice  | invoice_item | product |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
| id        | id           | id      | 
| fk_userID | desc         | name    |
|           | quantity     | price   |
|           | sum          |         |
|           | fk_invoiceID |         |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
```

It seems logical that `invoice_item` has a foreign key referenced to `product`.
But what happens if a product is deleted? If they are related, then row in the item_list will be deleted or set to null.

And that will not work if you want to look at an old invoice and the product is no longer available.

So, should `Product` and `Item_list` be related?

Comment: Don't delete your products. have a from_date and a (nullable) to_date and don't display them if to_date is not null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot remove a product once it has been defined, so add a Status field to the product that - in this example I'm using an enum, although it could easily be an INT or a set of bools (i.e. Archived),  I use [Parameter Enumeration Tables](http://chateau-logic.com/content/parameter-enumeration-tables) for this but that's a seperate answer.

The most important thing is to ensure that the invoice line has the pricing (and description) taken from the product at the point of order, to ensure that any future pricing changes or product name changes don't affect pre-existing invoices.

The other technique that I have used (quite succesfully) is to introduce the concept of *superceding* entities in a database - so that the original record remains and a new version is inserted whenever data is changed. To do this I add the following fields :

- currentID
- supersededById
- previousId

It makes the queries a little more cumbersome - but especially for addresses it is essential to ensure that the invoices remain constant and that address changes aren't reflected in the invoices - e.g. changing company name shouldn't change previously raised invoices.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `Invoice` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Invoice Item` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`desc` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
`value` DECIMAL(11,3) NOT NULL ,
`quantity` DECIMAL(11,3) NOT NULL ,
`total` DECIMAL(11,3) NOT NULL ,
`fk_id_Invoice` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
`fk_id_Product` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Product` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Price` DECIMAL(11,3) NOT NULL ,
`Name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
`Status` ENUM NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Invoice Item` ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_Invoice) REFERENCES `Invoice` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `Invoice Item` ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_Product) REFERENCES `Product` (`id`);
```

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. Addresses are never deleted in my address table. So if customer changes billing address, a new ID is used :)

Comment: Which tool did you use to great the image?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/ - javascript runs in a browser, it's simple and really easy to use.

Comment: I have a similar situation and your answer really helped. Still there's a specific point which I can't wrap my head around. I agree with *"The most important thing is to ensure that the invoice line has the pricing (and description) taken from the product at the point of order"*, however with that being the case, why should `Invoice Item` still refer *(has a FK)* to `Product`? Is there a good reason for keeping the relationship? And does dropping it has a downside?

Comment: Need the FK on invoice item for referential integrity; to ensure that you only invoice valid products. It is also useful in reporting, e.g. to find out which products have been invoiced and the net value of sales.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an additional column as no_of_stock, in the product table. If the product is empty in the inventory or is not used currently, should not be deleted, instead that column's value will be set to 0. Which will mean that though product cann ot be sold currently, but was previously sold, having the past existense

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is it normal to do it this way?

Comment: Yes it is absolutely normal mate :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want people to be able to see their old invoices, no matter how long ago they were generated, and including all information, then you shouldn't delete products. Just add a column containing an `ENUM('active', 'inactive') NOT NULL` or similar to distinguish those products you currently offer from those you only keep around for old references.

Comment: Similar answer to @Sashi Kant. So this solution is standard?