# Avoid duplicating fields across multiple tables

Tags: database, database-design

Let me describe briefly the table structures:

**Customer Table**

```
id | name | address_line_one | address_line_two | contact_no_one
```

**SaleInvoice Table**

```
id | id_Customer (Foreign Key) | invoice_no
```

If I have to print a Sale invoice, I have to use the Customer information (like name, address) from the Customer table.
Assume that after a year, some customer data changes (like name or address), and I update the new data in my customer table. Now, if the customer asks for an old invoice, it will be printed with the new customer data which shall be legally wrong.

Does that mean, I have to create

> name_customer
>
> address_line_one_customer
>
> ...

and all these fields in the Sale Invoice table too?

If yes, is there a better way to get data from these fields in Customer table to the Sale Invoice table then to write a SQL query to get the values and then set the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help designing my invoice db structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450032/need-help-designing-my-invoice-db-structure)

Comment: Hi. (As one can expect:) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. And don't settle for one suggested duplicate in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a problem easily solved by placing the Employee table in version normal form (VNF). This is actually just a flavor of 2nf but done in a way that provides the ability to query current data and past data using the same query.

A datetime parameter is used to provide the distinction. When the value is set to NOW, the current data is returned. When the value is set to a specific datetime value in the past, the data that was current at that date and time is returned.

A brief discussion of the particulars can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505253/3658753). That answer also contains links to more information if you think it is something that would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is really up to you. In some cases, where it is a legal document, you will save all the details so that you can always bring it up the way it was created. Alternatively if you are producing pdf invoices then save them to be 100% sure.

The other alternative is to create a CustomerHistory table, so that past versions are always saved with a date range, so that you can go back to the old version.

It depends on the use cases, but those are your main options.